# Problem importing an excel workbook into Access and adding a column; error 3127

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a form in an Access database that allows a user to import an Excel workbook into the database, then inserts a column with that day's date as a way to log when the record was imported, with the idea that I can later compare this to a master database and update accordingly.

My code is below:

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click()

'create a new file system object that will check for conditions and import the file as a new table if a valid name is chosen

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim strSQL As String
'Dim curDatabase As Object
    Dim tableTest As Object
    Dim fieldNew As Object
    Dim todayDate As Date
    Dim tempTable As String
    
   tempTable = "TempTable" & CStr(Date)
    'MsgBox TempTable
    
    'If no file name in box
    If Nz(Me.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'If a file name is in box and the file can be located
    If FSO.FileExists(Me.txtFileName) Then
        
        fileImport.ImportExcel Me.txtFileName, tempTable
    
    'once it imports the table, it then adds today's date (the upload date)
        
        todayDate = Date
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO  tempTable (Upload_Date) Values (#" & Date & "#);"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

        'DoCmd.RunSQL ("DROP Table TempTable")
    Else
    'Error message if file can't be found
        MsgBox "File not found."
    End If
    

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, right now I am getting two problems.

The first is

> run-time error 3127: The INSERT INTO statement contains an unknown
> field name.

I thought I wanted to insert a new field, so I'm a little perplexed by this error.

I'm also getting another error; the compiler doesn't seem to like when I use `tempTable` for the table name.  I'm trying to use a reference to the table name, rather than the actual name of the table itself, because this will end up being a daily upload, so the name of the table that is having this column inserted into it will change every day.

I appreciate any guidance that you can give; I'm fairly new to VBA.

**UPDATE:**  I ended up solving this issue by A. using an `UPDATE` statement and using `CurrentDb.Execute` to add the date. I found that this worked for me:

```
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD COLUMN Upload_Date DATE;"
strSQL2 = "UPDATE TempTable SET Upload_Date = '" & Date & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2
```

Comment: Since you are updating a datetime field, it is interesting code did not error out with single quote enclosures. Check if `UPDATE` effectively ran. Also, best practice in databases is to not update schema on fly with `ALTER` but anticipate all fields in advance during the planning stage of your relational model. And relatedly, never date suffix, many tables as that is ill-advised design. Read up on normalization.

Comment: @Parfait I appreciate the feedback.  The update query worked like that; that seemed to be the formatting that I had to use to make it happen, I guess.  I'm having to add that `UPDATE` and `ALTER` statements to insert the column and date so that I can compare a table that is currently in this database with this table, then either add or remove things from the main table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. `INSERT INTO` doesn't add columns, it just adds rows (with data in existing columns). Look into `ALTER TABLE` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql )
2. I'm not sure if it's related, but the table name you use in `strSQL` is "tempTable", yet the table name you pass to `fileImport.ImportExcel` is "TempTable" (i.e. the capitalization of the first letter is inconsistent).

Comment: I was hoping to use  'tempTable' as a reference to the table, rather than an explicit table name.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable "tempTable" is meant to hold the name of the table (so it can be used for different table names) then it should be outside of the SQL strings:

```
strSQL= "ALTER TABLE " & tempTable " & " ADD COLUMN Upload_Date DATE;"
strSQL2 = "UPDATE " & tempTable & " SET Upload_Date = '" & Date & "';"
```

Otherwise you are amending and updating a table called "TempTable" rather than inserting the calculated table name from the variable into the SQL string.
Also note that there should be a semi-colon at the end of strSQL2 as well.